# using ode45 for descriptive forms

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

Using Matlab what would be the most efficient way to solve,

$A_1x'(t) = A_2x(t)$, where both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are $n\times n$ matrices.

Both are sparse matrices and hence I want to avoid inversion.